# How to start a perl webserver with systemd?

Tags: systemd, perl, webserver

I copied this this file (vokabel_daemon.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=Start vokabeltrainer daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/mm/lib/vokabeltrainer/box_vokabeltrainer.pl daemon --listen "http://*:3001"

[Install]
WantedBy=mulit-user.target
```

to `/etc/systemd/system/` (openSUSE12.1).

Then after a

```
systemctl enable vokabel_daemon.service
systemctl start vokabel_daemon.service
```

I could open my website.

But after a reboot it doesn't work any more.

`systemctl status vokabel_daemon.service`:

```
vokabel_daemon.service - Start vokabeltrainer daemon
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vokabel_daemon.service; enabled)
          Active: inactive (dead)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vokabel_daemon.service
```

After a `systemctl start vokabel_daemon.service` it is working again:

```
vokabel_daemon.service - Start vokabeltrainer daemon
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vokabel_daemon.service; enabled)
          Active: active (running) since Thu, 21 Jun 2012 08:38:16 +0200; 1s ago
        Main PID: 2288 (perl)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vokabel_daemon.service
                  └ 2288 perl /home/mm/lib/vokabeltrainer/box_vokabeltrainer.pl daemon --listen http://*:3001
```

What do I have to change so that I don't have to start the daemon by hand after a reboot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this isn't a typo, the `install` section in your typo service file contains a typo. It should be, `multi-user.target` instead of `mulit-user.target` (`mulit` vs. `multi`), e.g:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```